# How do I escape reserved words used as column names on HIVE?

Tags: hive, escaping, reserved-words

When I am executing following query in HIVE, it is giving me current date instead of the column values from USER_INFO table.

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE 
FROM   USER_INFO
LIMIT 1;
```

How do I escape reserved words used as column names on HIVE?

Thanks & Regards,
Kamlesh

Answer (score 4):

Got it.

There are two ways

1 You can use apostrophe before and after the keyword as shown below.

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE 
FROM   `USER_INFO`
LIMIT 1;
```

2 There is setting shown below which you can do if you are executing it with unix shell (i.e. with sh command)

```
hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks & Regards,
Kamleshkumar Gujarathi

Comment: Down-voted until fixed. **(1)** The wrong element is quoted **(2.1)** This has nothing to do with shell. **(2.2)** This works only for some keywords, not all of them

Comment: The escape character shown here is "backtick" or "accent grave" (code point 0060) not "apostrophe"

Answer (score 2):

In order to query reserved words in columns (for example "users" or "current_date")

```
SELECT `CURRENT_DATE` 
FROM   USER_INFO
LIMIT 1;
```

Notice the aposthrope type  **`** (As Wheezil points out this character is 'backtick' , but I want to point out that in international keyboards this character is relatively hard to type )

Self answer is ok but misleading due to wrong query, adding answer here for future reference.

Comment: The escape character shown here is "backtick" or "accent grave" (code point 0060) not "apostrophe"

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue with the keyword "application". Even backtick is not working.

select `application`
from abc.def
where transaction is not null
and  load_date = '20221115';

Error -
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: line 1:7 Invalid table alias or column reference 'application': (possible column names are: date, transaction, status, direction, message_type, smi, medium, medium_type, aircraft, flight, callsign, dep_icao, arr_icao, application_str, from_to, machine, msg_length, msg_text, attached_files, load_date)

Any other solution ?